# Error when calling $this->class::constant

Tags: php, class, attributes

I have some sets of classes with constans.

And short code like this:

```
$this->class = $class;
$this->class::constans;
```

But it causes Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM.

But when I call constans like this:

```
$class::constans
```

Its ok.

Is there a way to keep class name as attribute and call to its constans?

Comment: Use `ClassName::Constats`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a constant dynamically in PHP, you can use the `constant()` function:

```
$constant_value = constant($this->class  . '::constant');
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you CAN NOT do so.
Assign `$this->class` to a local variable, or use class name instead of object (ClassName::constans) or you even can just alias your class [class_alias](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you're question correctly you would like to know how you can access you're constans constant within your class. I expect that you're $class represents something like,

```
   $class = new Something_Class();
```

Try using

```
    $this->class->constans
```

Also I would not use class as a variable name.